# Open YouKu application via URL

Tags: android, eclipse, url, youku

This code takes me to the browser if I don't have the YouKu application, does anybody know the code if I have the YouKu application?

This code takes to the browser, it happens if the YouKu application wasn't installed

```
film.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XMTQ4OTQ5Nzc2OA==_ev_2.html?from=y1.3-idx-uhome-1519-20887.205805-205902.2-1"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }
        });
```

I hope Chinese are here!

Answer (score 0):

try this way [start application with package name](http://blog.csdn.net/mad1989/article/details/38090513)

Comment: Thank you, I'll do that when I get home and let you know!

Comment: I tried the code, my knowledge about it is less than 2%, can you please write the entire code here for http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XMzA3MDE2NTg4.html?from=s1.8-1-1.2 for example, please@ :)